# MPI_Bcast deadlock

Tags: mpi, broadcast

I have this code, where master sends initial data to his slaves. It uses MPI_Bcast (broadcast) function but when the Broadcast is called, the master continues but the slaves are stuck in deadlock.

Code snippets are following:

```
Master {
    run() {
        ...
        MPI_Pack(&offset, 1, MPI_INT, buffer, BUFFERSIZE, &position, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Pack(&dataSize, 1, MPI_INT, buffer, BUFFERSIZE, &position, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Pack(dataLoader.getData(), dataSize*dataSize, MPI_CHAR, buffer, BUFFERSIZE, &position, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Bcast(buffer, position, MPI_PACKED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("master ok");
    }
}

Slave {
    run() {
        MPI_Bcast(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, MPI_PACKED, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        printf("Slave OK");
        //unpack
        MPI_Unpack(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, &position, &offset, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        MPI_Unpack(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, &position, &dataSize, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        data = new char[dataSize * dataSize];
        MPI_Unpack(buffer, BUFFERSIZE, &position, data, dataSize*dataSize, MPI_CHAR, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    }
}
```

The output would be:
    Master ok

and the slave would stop responding.
Thanks for help

Answer (score 1):

`mpi_bcast` should be called by all processes in the communicator and they should all encounter the call at the same point in the code.  As you have written your (pseudo-)code the root process makes a call to broadcast which the worker processes do not, and the worker processes make a call which the root does not.

`mpi_bcast` is one of MPI's *collective* routines, the library takes care of determining the correct pattern of message sending based on the arguments you pass to it.  In the case of `mpi_bcast` the 4th argument is the id of the source of the broadcast (it doesn't need to be the root process of the communicator though it often is); all the other processes in the communicator will be receivers.

Comment: well all of the processes call mpi_bcast() only once in the program. There is nothing data dependent in front of those calls so there can be no hangup there. The thing is - it works on my notebook with in place processes but hangs up on cluster.